# Django: int() argument must be a string , a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Game'

Tags: python, django

Here's my code,

```
objects = sorted(Game.objects.filter(...), key=lambda x: random.random())
items = Game.objects.exclude(pk__in=objects)
```

But, i'm getting this error,

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'Game'

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arpit suggests, you need to add the pk value. You could also modify the items variable like this

```
items = Game.objects.exclude(pk__in=[o.pk for o in objects])
```

Compared to Arpit's solution this won't throw a list index out of range.

Comment: Working Fine, Thank you sir :)

Comment: Thank you @Randomix, if you feel so inclined, do accept the answer :)

Comment: Sure. why not ;)

Answer (score 2):

`pk` is `primary_key` which needs to be `a string, a bytes-like object or a number` as your error suggests. You are filtering it with a list of objects of type `Game`. Possible fix:

```
object_ids = [obj.pk for obj in sorted(Game.objects.filter(...), key=lambda x: random.random())]
items = Game.objects.exclude(pk__in=object_ids)
```